# Can I set bookmarks in WP7?

Tags: internet-explorer, windows-phone-7, mobile, bookmarks

Is it possible to  set bookmarks in Windows Phone 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no programmatic API to interact with WP7's IE7 bookmarks. The best thing you can do is open up a website using the WebBrowserTask and then the user can add a bookmark if they choose to do so.

Normally on IE it's possible to invoke the Javascript "window.external.AddFavorite()" method to ask a browser to add a favourite, but that doesn't appear to work in IE7 mobile.